# Code Igniter - Como chamar uma procedure que está em outro banco de dados?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um SQL Server onde temos diversos databases e seus schemas.
Até ai tudo bem, porem preciso acessar uma stored procedure que esta no banco X.

Tentei assim : $this->db->query("cadunico.dbo.CadUnico_Educacao_Consultar");
porem quando quero debugar, nao é retornado nada.

Comment: Não faltou a instrução EXECUTE? Procedimentos armazenados geralmente são acionados na forma: EXECUTE *nome_do_procedimento* *parâmetro(s)*

Comment: O usuário da conexão tem direito de visualizar objetos de outra database? É outra database apenas ou outro banco mesmo? Quando há outro banco envolvido é necessário outra conexão, que precisa ser criada manualmente, e gera outro objeto no $this, assim `$query = $this->meu_db_especial->query('EXECUTE CadUnico_Educacao_Consultar');`.